# What is the format of ffmpeg -vstats_file?

Tags: ffmpeg, xuggler, pyffmpeg

When i run my FFMPEG command along with -vstats_file , one of the lines are

> frame=   182 q= 9.0 f_size=  17215 s_size=     3782kB time= 23238.835 br=  1418.5kbits/s avg_br=     1.3kbits/s type= P

In here can somebody explain me what is the format of "Time"

The Duration of the video file is 20.36s(Seconds). Assuming the time above is in milliseconds its pretty much higher than the length of the origin la video file.

Answer (score 0):

The value should be in seconds and is obtained using:

```
ti1 = av_stream_get_end_pts(ost->st) * av_q2d(ost->st->time_base);
```

where `av_q2d` converts a rational to a double.

You could try to set the **PTS** to zero.

Comment: I dont think its in seconds. Because the video duration which i ran accross is just 20 seconds . Even if we assume the value as milliseconds , its actually 3-5 seconds larger than the actual duration

Comment: On 2.6.git is in seconds. Check your PTS values and see if they start at 0 or try to force them to start at 0.